# Does sqlalchemy support table join in memory?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Problem:

I have some tables to manipulate, some of the tables remain unchanged and some tables change frequently. The unchanged table has limited records which could all be loaded into memory. so I just want to do the "join" operation in memory, that is, load the unchanged table into memory, then "join" the result with the records on disk.

I am using the sqlalchemy as the ORM framework, does sqlalchemy support this kind of "join" operation?

Comment: Basically you don't join in SQLAlchemy, SQLAlchemy joins for you. And I don't see any reason why that should not work on an in-memory database.

Comment: @ Klaus D, is there any example? I want to load all the unchanged table into memory, but the frequently changed table on hard disc, so the join operation is half from memory, half from disc, can any demo show this?

Comment: You want to do a join over two DBs, one in memory and one on the HD?

Comment: @ Klaus D,  yes, but join over two tables

Comment: I'm still unsure what you are trying to do. Please explain more detailed!

Comment: well, i have so many this kind of "join" operations which made the whole process very slow, I want to speed up this operation, so the possibly way is to do this kind of join operation in memory, as I said, some tables could be cached but some are not, so I want to know if sqlalchemy support this kind of operation?  If not, I'm afraid I have to write the code myself.

Comment: Sorry, but without any details there can't be any detailed help.